# How to map a property of type enum when querying the db in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have an object I am trying to get from the database.
The object has a property of `enum` type. When querying the database I am getting an error:

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'MyProject.Schema'. A member of the type, 'SchemaTypeString', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

The model:

```
    [NotMapped]
    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
    public SchemaType SchemaType { get; set; }

    [Column("SchemaType")]
    public string SchemaTypeString
    {
        get { return SchemaType.ToString(); }
        private set { SchemaType = EnumExtensions.ParseEnum<SchemaType>(value); }
    }
```

In the `DbContext` I also specify that the `SchemaType` column should be mapped to `SchemaTypeString` property.

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<DataSchema>()
            .Property(e => e.SchemaTypeString)
            .HasColumnName("SchemaType");
```

And this is the line that throws an error mentioned above:

```
var obj = db.DataSchemas.SqlQuery("exec dbo.DataSchema_Select @ID", new SqlParameter("ID", id)).ToList();
```

I ma using EF6 so there is not way of using `HasConversion` like in EF Core

Comment: EF6 `SqlQuery` method is known to not use the column mappings. The expectation is that the column names in the returned query match the object *property* names. So in your SP, you have to use column alias like `select SchemaType as SchemaTypeString, …`.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So what `HasColumnName` is for at all?

Comment: For EF generated queries/commands. Raw SQL is exception. Consider it EF6 `SqlQuery` method defect/limitation.